# Banner with multiple links

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, com-banners

Using the Joomla built-in banner component, is it possible to have more than one link in a banner?

I need to add a "disclaimer link" to some of my banners. Say my ad looks like this:

[image: Example banner]

I would like the blue part to be the main link, and the red part to link to a PDF with additional information.

So far I've done it using custom code and an image map:

```
<img id="myID" src="url/to/banner.jpg" border="0" width="250" height="250" usemap="#myMap" alt="" />
<map name="myMap" id="myID">
<area href="http://mainlink.com" shape="rect" coords="0,0,217,250"  target="_blank"     />
<area href="http://disclaimer.com" shape="rect" coords="0,217,250,250" target="_blank"     />
</map>
```

It works, but it doesn't look like the clicks are tracked by Joomla.

Any other ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a third party Joomla banners component, but I'm not sure even those would be set up for multiple links per banner.

This would require heavy customization to the banner component because there's no database field to collect the second link's data.

So you'd need to create one and post to it when the other link's data posts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was afraid that was the only solution. I'll see if I can find a third party component to use.

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up on this, I ended up using a HTML Image Map. In order to track the  clicks on the different areas, I used a nice, free click tracking system called [PHP Click counter](http://www.phpjunkyard.com/php-click-counter.php). It's not a Joomla extension, but a standalone PHP click tracking system. Works perfectly, but I have to log in to a different admin panel in order to see the number of clicks.